# get and show data from another tables laravel

Tags: php, laravel, get, html-table

I already saved data in a table(table2) getting info of another table(table1), the problem is when I show the data of the  (table2) I get the id, but not the name.

```
class PagosController extends Controller
{
     public function index()
    {

         $datos=Pago::all();
         $pagos=servicios::all()->pluck('name','id');

      return view ('pagos.create',compact('pagos'),compact('datos'));
    }
}
```

in the view

```
@if($datos)
        <table class="table">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <td>ID</td>
                    <td>Fecha de Pago</td>
                    <td>Precio</td>

                    <td>Servicio</td>
                    <td></td>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>

                @foreach($datos as $row)
                <tr>
                    <td>{{$row->id}}</td>
                    <td>{{$row->fechap}}</td>
                     <td>{{$row->precio}}</td>
                    <td>{{$row->id_servicio}}</td>
                    <td><a href="{{route('users.edit',$row->id)}}" class="btn btn-info">Editar</a></td>
                   <form action="{{route('users.destroy',$row->id)}}" method="post">
                       <td> <input name="_method" type="hidden" value="Delete">
                <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{csrf_token()}}">
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger">Eliminar</button>
            </form>
                        </td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
                   @endforeach 

        </table>


    @endif
```

and the variable $pagos, I use in another view to get info of a table

```
 {!! Form::select('pagos',$pagos,null,['id'=>'pagos']) !!}
```

Comment: Please provide more information on your code. there are following possibilities but not limited to following: 1- controller is not receiving the request completely (rare but happens). please `dd` your request and check that. 2-`name` is not a `fillable` attribute in your model.

Comment: ok,Thanks! maybe i cannot explain, in the view i can see perfectly the fields of the table but i want to show a field that is a foreign key of the other table, i can see just the id, but i need to show the name. In the table(html) the  field id_servicio is the id of the table servicio, how i can show the name? (table Pagos, vatiable $datos, at the begin of the question )